match.call() removes missing arguments
I am developing a method [ for an S4 class. The array in question can have a varying number of dimensions so the method declaration uses dot-dot-dot to allow for as many arguments as there are dimensions in the underlying array. The function below shows the correct definition and having the mock substance of simply returning the result of the match.call() function:
setMethod("[", "myClass", function (x, ...) {
  match.call()
})

This works as expected when arguments are provided for all dimensions, here with object obj being an instance of myClass:
> z <- obj[23, 56:65, 9]
> lapply(z, print)
`[`
v16
[1] 23
56:65
[1] 9
[[1]]
`[`

$x
v16

$i
[1] 23

$j
56:65

[[5]]
[1] 9

(I have no idea why the 3rd and 4th elements in the list are named i and j, while further elements are not named. Bonus points for who can explain that.)
It also works when the last argument is missing:
> z <- v16[23, 56:65, ]
> lapply(z, print)
`[`
v16
[1] 23
56:65

[[1]]
`[`

$x
v16

$i
[1] 23

$j
56:65

[[5]]
         #### Empty symbol here

Any missing arguments before the last one, however, are simply ignored and do not show up at all (note how there are only 4 elements in the resulting lists):
> z <- obj[23, , 9]
> lapply(z, print)
`[`
v16
[1] 23
[1] 9
[[1]]
`[`

$x
v16

$i
[1] 23

[[4]]
[1] 9

> z <- v16[ , 56:65, 9]
> lapply(z, print)
`[`
v16
56:65
[1] 9
[[1]]
`[`

$x
v16

$j
56:65

[[4]]
[1] 9

Is there a way that I can keep the missing arguments prior to the last one so that I can substitute them for something else in my function?

setMethod silently conforms the formals of your method to those of the generic function: compare getGeneric("[") and selectMethod("[", "myClass").  match.call names non-missing arguments matched to x, i, j, and drop, because those are the named arguments of the method and, well, that is the documented behaviour of match.call.

Yeah, it sounds like you don't want the matching part of match.call(). Try sys.call() instead.

@MikaelJagan Ah right, I didn't check the generic. You got my +1 for that issue.

@MrFlick That seems to do the trick. Make it an answer and you have my vote.
